# Cannot download .sql, .flag, .tmp, .InstallState files with WebClient

Tags: c#

I'm trying to download some files from a virtual directory using WebClient class and DownloadFile method, all files download good except files with .sql, .flag, .tmp, . InstallState extensions. I get the "HTTP Error 404 - File or directory not found" error. This extensions are not in the Application Configuration Mappings, so what do I have to configure in order to download this files? Because I can't figure it out. Thx. (I'm using windows server 2003 )

Comment: My guess would be IIS is serving up a 404 as a security measure.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is that the web server probably doesn't have MIME types configured for these file extensions.

Because these are being served as static files over HTTP you'll need to add them.

If these files are residing on a public facing server administered by you, do you think it's wise to be serving these? Why not obtain via FTP?